# How to remove duplicated column in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, indexing, duplicates

I need some help with my Data Wrangling in Python, using pandas.
I am appending dataframes in a loop (one or two rows per iteration). For an unknown reason I have duplicated columns when appending which occur only in a few iterations, resulting in the following dataframe:

```
ID  Nom. value       0         1           2           3       ...
1001    -857    -856.989    -856.989    -857.042    -857.042   ...
1001    335     334.987     334.987     335.006     335.006    ...
...
```

Is there a way to do this systematically in the loop (dataframe is large and consists of many iterations)? I need this dataframe instead:

```
ID  Nom. value       0         1        ...
1001    -857    -856.989    -857.042    ...
1001    335     334.987     335.006     ...
...
```

Thanks!

Comment: What programming language are you using? What library for data frames? Please tag your question accordingly - proper tagging ensures that your question is shown to 1) more people and 2) experts in technologies you're working with.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am sorry, the code is required is what I am asking for. I have a dataframe with duplicated columns and I would like to do in pandas is a way to eliminate the duplicated columns. The header of the columns is just an integer starting at 0 and extending to about 100 (so about 50 columns to remove). This is easily done in rows, but I do not know a way to do it for columns. Would be your recommendation to transpose a subselection of the dataframe columns, eliminate the now converted rows and then transposing again?